# Loading data to Netezza using nzload utility

Tags: file-upload, netezza, bulk-load

I am trying to load data into Netezza database using "nzload" utility. The control file is as below and it works without any issues.

Is there a way to provide multiple data files as the input in a single control file?

```
DATAFILE C:\Karthick\data.txt        
{
    Database    test1
    TableName   test
    Delimiter   '%'
    maxErrors    20
    Logfile     C:\Karthick\importload.log
    Badfile     C:\Karthick\inventory.bad
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ cat my_control_file
    datafile my_file1 {}
    datafile my_file2 {}
    datafile my_file3 {}
    datafile my_file4 {}

# Below, I specify many of the options
# on the command line itself ... so I don't have
# to repeat them in the control file.

    $ nzload -db system -t my_table -delim "|" -maxerrors 10 -cf my_control_file
    Load session of table 'MY_TABLE' completed successfully
    Load session of table 'MY_TABLE' completed successfully
    Load session of table 'MY_TABLE' completed successfully
    Load session of table 'MY_TABLE' completed successfully
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to mange how to handle null file for a specific column ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify multiple data files in single control file. Those data files can be loaded to same table or different tables. See an example at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=command-nzload-control-file

Following are two data files "/tmp/try1.dat" and "/tmp/try2.dat" to be loaded in a table "test" in "system" database:

```
[nz@nps ]$ cat /tmp/try1.dat
1
2
[nz@nps ]$ cat /tmp/try2.dat
3
4
```

Following control file defines two "DATAFILE" blocks one for each data file.

```
[nz@nps ]$ cat /tmp/try.cf
DATAFILE /tmp/try1.dat
{
    Database    system
    TableName   test
    Delimiter   '|'
    Logfile     /tmp/try1.log
    Badfile     /tmp/try1.bad
}
DATAFILE /tmp/try2.dat
{
    Database    system
    TableName   test
    Delimiter   '|'
    Logfile     /tmp/try2.log
    Badfile     /tmp/try2.bad
}
```

Load the data using "nzload -cf" option and verify that data is loaded.

```
[nz@nps ]$ nzload -cf /tmp/try.cf
Load session of table 'TEST' completed successfully
Load session of table 'TEST' completed successfully
[nz@nps ]$ nzsql -c "select * from test"
 A1
----
  2
  3
  4
  1
(4 rows)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).